# Traversing within javascript object in for loop

Tags: javascript, object

I want to refer to an object within the object itself. The following is not right, i know. But what is the right way?

And when googling for such problems, what would be the right keywords to search for?

```
for (var key in eName) {
       var obj = eName[key];
       eName[key] = {
        type: 'id',
        name: obj.substr(1),
        html: this.type + '="' + this.name +'"'  //<--- here

       }
    }
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you are trying to achieve? What do you need this for/what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: html: this.type + '="' + obj.substr(1) +'"' :)

Comment: Hmm. Are you referring to "this" when "this" isn't created yet...? So "this" is actually that - The "this" from the outer scope function...

Comment: when commenting on someone else comment use `@` like I did here to notify him/her otherwise you won't get any response. first three letters are enough assuming there isn't anyone else with name starting in those letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the JS equivalent for `class` instead:

```
for (var key in eName) {
    var obj = eName[key];
    eName[key] = new CustomElement(obj);
}

...

function CustomElement(strData) {
    this.type = "id";
    this.name = strData.substr(1);
    this.html = this.type + '="' + this.name +'"';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`The this keyword`](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html) for Javascript might help you understand what `this` really means.  You might have to pass it in as an object to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (var key in eName) {
       var obj = eName[key];
       eName[key] = {
        type: 'id',
        name: obj.substr(1),
        html: ''  //<--- here

       }
eName[key].html = eName[key].type + '="' + eName[key].name +'"'

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var key in eName) {
       var obj = eName[key];
       eName[key] = {
        type: 'id',
        name: obj.substr(1),
        html: function() { return this.type + '="' + this.name +'"' }

       }
    }
```

Then you would use eName[key].html()